# Why is my data suddenly ugly when using FirestoreListView?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've been "manually" reading data into a listview from Firestore and writing into customized ListTiles to display in my UI. Here's the current code for that:

```
class FetchTransactionsByDate extends StatelessWidget {
  FetchTransactionsByDate({
    super.key,
    required this.dbRef,
  });

  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> dbRef;
  final formatCurrency = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      //* How to use Riverpod here?
      stream: dbRef.orderBy('date', descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
            //* Should be objects?
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return TransactionDetailView(
                    title: "${document['payee']}",
                  );
                }));
              },
              child: TransactionTile(
                topLeft: "${document['payee']}",
                bottomLeft: "${document['date']}",
                topright: document['amount'],
                bottomRight: "${document['costcode']}",
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),);},);}}
```

And here's the list it produces:
[image: Manual List]

Here's the code for the FirestoreListView (cribbed from pub.dev example):

```
class RecentTransactionsList extends StatelessWidget {
  RecentTransactionsList({super.key});

  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final transactionsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users/$uid/transactions')
        .orderBy('date', descending: true);
    return FirestoreListView<Map<String, dynamic>>(
      query: transactionsQuery,
      itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
        Map<String, dynamic> item = snapshot.data();
        return TransactionTile(
          topLeft: "${item['payee']}",
          bottomLeft: "${item['date']}",
          topright: item['amount'],
          bottomRight: "${item['job']}",
        );},);}}
```

And here's the list THAT produces:
[image]

How can I make the FirestoreListView look like my other list views? And, just as importantly - why does it look so different, when I'm using the same TransactionTile class to build and return the ListTiles?

Comment: Wrapped FirestoreListView... with Theme(data: Theme.of(context). Results: no change in the UI even after hard restart.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to wrap the FirestoreListView in a Scaffold. (Actually, Scaffold / SafeArea / Column / Expanded). Problem solved.